# Mask edit text box focus

Tags: c#, wpf

I am using mask edit TextBox.The textbox always shows 0 (zero). I cannot type any key from the keyboard. I need to delete the zero first then I can type digits. Therefore I am doing extra steps here. Is it possible to type as soon as I type from the keyboard? Any suggestion is welcome.

```
private void DateDay_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((TextBox)sender).Text == "Day")
        ((TextBox)sender).Text = string.Empty;
}

private void DateDay_LostFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (((TextBox)sender).Text == string.Empty)
        ((TextBox)sender).Text = "Day";
    else
        CheckForCorrectDateDay((TextBox)sender);
}
```

I have tried with Focus event but not successful:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to select all content in the textbox in `GotFocus` event. For MaskedTextBox control it handle the selection internally after the focus event fire. So we need to do `BeginInvoke` to call the `SelectAll()` afterward.

```
private void DateDay_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
        this.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)delegate() {
            ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
        });  
}
```

This way you can start typing directly.
You can't make the text null if null is not allowed.

WPF version:

```
private void TextBox_GotFocus(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, (ThreadStart)delegate() {
        ((TextBox)sender).SelectAll();
    });
}
```

Comment: Not working.its click in the Textbox the Zero is not focused.So i can not type.

Comment: Sorry, for maskedtextbox it handle the selection internally, so you must select it using the BeginInvoke that will fire after the internal selection occurs. I have edit the answer.

Comment: hey thanks it works for me.As i mentioned wpf so just modified

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution for MaskedTextBox using the Enter Event

```
    private void maskedEdit_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MaskedTextBox maskedTextBox = (MaskedTextBox)sender;
        maskedTextBox.BeginInvoke
        (new Action
            (() =>
                {
                    maskedTextBox.SelectAll();
                }
            )
        );            
    }
```